# Matching two criteria for filter in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

**Edit**

I copied and pasted a comment I posted in a reply:

> ... query is working as it should. I posted this question in those times when you feel cornered and you don't know what else to try. The error was not in the query nor Elasticsearch, it was because I added new fields to the Post and Lambda Function was failing to index new Posts (`dynamic: false`). To top it off I didn't had the proper CloudWatch alarms on the Lambda logs. I realized that after analyzing Kibana logs. I assumed posts were created because they appeared on the comment section (main storage is Dynamo), but those posts were not indexed in Elasticsearch.

**Original question**

I have thousands of documents (Posts) indexed in Elasticsearch and I'm trying to make a simple query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE comment LIKE '%comment%'
  AND created_at >= '2019-04-03'
```

I have tried different approaches using `and` and `bool` queries:

#### `bool` query

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "comment": "comment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "created_at": {
                            "gte": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

I'm getting an empty result set:

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

#### `and` query

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "and": {
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "comment": "comment"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "updated_at": {
                                    "gte": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

Parsing Exception:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "no [query] registered for [filtered]",
                "line": 5,
                "col": 21
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "no [query] registered for [filtered]",
        "line": 5,
        "col": 21
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

#### Analyzer

I'm using the following custom analyzer:

```
{
  analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      custom_analyzer: {
        tokenizer: 'custom_tokenizer',
        filter: 'lowercase'
      }
    },
    tokenizer: {
      custom_tokenizer: {
        type: 'ngram',
        min_gram: 2,
        max_gram: 16,
        token_chars: [
          'letter',
          'digit',
          'punctuation',
          'symbol'
        ]
      }
    },
  }
}
```

#### Expected result

When I run separate queries one for `match` in `comment` and other for `range` in `created_at` i get what it should return:

**Search by text in `comment`**:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "comment": "comment"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 888,
        "max_score": 1.9128458,
        "hits": [...]
    }
}
```

**Search by date `range` in `created_at`**:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "created_at": {
                            "gte": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

```
{
    "took": 7,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 19,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits: [...]
    }
}
```

I'm quite sure there're Posts created after `March 3rd` with `comment` text in the `comment` field I added test data with comments containing that substring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment or message directly, but can you provide additional clarification?

I attempted to re-create the issue, as your first search example should work as expected.  To confirm this, I created a simple index and added a few records to test the different queries you provided:

```
POST demo/_doc
{
  "created_at": "2019-04-02T12:00:00.000Z",
  "comment": "contains comment"
}

POST demo/_doc
{
  "created_at": "2019-04-03T12:00:00.000Z",
  "comment": "contains another comment"
}

POST demo/_doc
{
  "created_at": "2019-04-03T12:00:00.000Z",
  "comment": "not what we are looking for"
}
```

*Note I didn't bother with the custom analyzer, as your individual queries indicate the individual searches are working correctly, so that should have no impact.*

From there, testing the individual queries yielded the expected results, and testing the original query you provided also yielded the expected results:

Query:

```
GET demo/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "comment": "comment"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took" : 17,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.287682,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "demo",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "-sxo72kBwpqm-gdssSYh",
        "_score" : 1.287682,
        "_source" : {
          "created_at" : "2019-04-03T12:00:00.000Z",
          "comment" : "contains another comment"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The only possibility that jumps out at me is you indicated in your last statement that there are posts created "after March 3rd with comment text in the comment field" which you created, but the queries are actually searching for posts with comment text in the comment field after *April* 3rd.  However, this could very well be a typo.

Alternatively, since there are only 19 hits returned by your second query (date range looking at `created_at` field), could you review those, find one with the comment field containing the `comment` text, and paste that or a snippet of it?

Comment: As you mentioned, query is working as it should. I posted this question in those times when you feel cornered and you don't know what else to try. The error was not in the query nor Elasticsearch, it was because I added new fields to the Post and Lambda Function was failing to index new Posts (`dynamic: false`). To top it off I didn't had the proper CloudWatch alarms on the Lambda logs. I realized that after analyzing Kibana logs.

Comment: Totally understand - I've found myself in those situations plenty of times - glad you were able to get it resolved!